# Error while invoking client for soap webservice

Tags: java, web-services, soap

I have created soap web service and generated its client. When I invoked it, i got this below error

> Two classes have the same XML type name "http://webservice.soap.com/}getKeyRequest". Use @XmlType.name and @XmlType.namespace to assign different names to them.

Generated code for client looks like below

GetKeyRequest.java

```
 @XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)

    @XmlType(name = "getKeyRequest", propOrder = {  //line 1

        "arg0"

    })

    public class GetKeyRequest {
        protected String arg0;
```

GetKeyRequestResponse.java

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)

@XmlType(name = "getKeyRequestResponse", propOrder = { //line 2

    "_return"

})

public class GetKeyRequestResponse {

    @XmlElement(name = "return")

    protected String _return;
```

After some tries, I reached to the conclusion that if I make the following changes it is working fine. Notice `getKeyRequest1` and `getKeyRequestResponse1` in the changes.

- line1 to `@XmlType(name = "getKeyRequest1", propOrder = {...`
- line2 to `@XmlType(name = "getKeyRequestResponse1", propOrder = ....`

Comment: Can you post the WSDL that you are working with?

Comment: I improved the formatting and did some rewording for better readability. Please mention what your question is exactly as you see to have found the solution based on your question.